# Mountain Lion - Finder - Search by file name

Tags: finder, search

I just upgraded from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion and I seem to be missing one bit of functionality that I used all the time in Finder. I could press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search for files by file name. Now pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> takes me to the "all my files" folder.

Did they reassign the keyboard shortcut for search by file name?

Comment: Yeah, it appears that the shortcut has be reassigned. I get the same results.

Comment: Also, what's the best way to find files by file name now?

Comment: Looks like command+F and prefacing the search with "name:" does the job.  Not quite as fast as I'm used to, but I suppose I shall adjust. *sigh*

Answer (score 5):

The keyboard shortcut was changed to ⌃⌘F.

If you open a window with ⌃⌘F, there is no indication in the UI that Finder is matching only filenames other than that the "Name matches" item in the suggestion list is selected:

[image]

Finder should only match filenames even if you don't press return though.

Answer (score 0):

When I hit ⌃⌘F, I'm taken to a new finder window, with the cursor placed in the search box. The default setting reads "Kind is Any" and it still searches for contents, not by filename.

There are only three ways I can find to search by filename is:

1. Type a phrase in finder search box, wait a second for the dropdown, and select "Name matches "
2. Change the search filter bar from "Kind is any" to "Name contains"
3. Type "name:" before your search phrase in the search box.

I'm still hoping for an easier way. A way to turn the search to search by filename contains by default. Anyone had any luck with this, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The UI is broken. You do not have to select the "name matches" option, it is simply the default and automatically selected when you hit enter. Instead, you can click away from it resulting in identical UI for both search methods, but one does in fact search the names only. Demo screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/GJt9qQp.png (10.8.2)